# Two submit buttons one form two different purposes

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have two submit buttons within a form. The first button does not fire while the second one does. The second button is hidden by default and shown only if users click on the span. I have a feeling the JavaScript plays a role in messing things around but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be awesome.

`HTML` File Code

```
  <form action="login.php" method="post">     
      <span style="cursor:pointer;" onclick='showSecondButton();' href="#">Forgot your login details?</span>
      //first button
      <input id='loginButton'  type="submit" name='loginNow' value="Login">
      //second button (hidden by default)
      <input id='newButton'  type="submit" name='recoverPassword' style='display:none; ' value="Recover Account">
  </form>
```

`PHP` file

```
if(isset($_POST['loginNow'])){//does not fire
    //login user
}
if(isset($_POST['recoverPassword'])){//fires
    //recover password
}
```

`JS` File

```
<script>
    function showSecondButton(){
        document.getElementById("loginButton").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("newButton").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @NabilAli - `You can't have two submit buttons in the same form` ... oh really?

Comment: @NabilAli: Not true. Done it many times before.

Comment: When you say `The first button does not fire` - have you checked the developer tools network tab?

Comment: Will the first button fire if you remove the second button?

Comment: @JaromandaX: Yes. I dont see nothing there. The button behaves like a submit button but nothing happens.

Comment: `I dont see nothing there. The button behaves like a submit button` - it's one or the other ... if it behaves like a submit button, then a POST must be in the network tab

Comment: Here's your code - https://jsfiddle.net/3m92muvh/ - it works fine - both buttons submit - some other code you are not showing is at fault

Comment: @NabilAli - despite the irrelevance of that with the code in the question, not even that is correct

Comment: @MudOnTire: I made tests and no.